# VBA Excel Macro Save as brain stall

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to enter a File Name to save an Excel sheet with option to change, all is working except pulling the file name from cells and  entering the the preferred file name code is below

```
Public Sub EnterInfo()

Dim ROOM As String
Dim SiteName As String
Dim SiteID As String
Dim FSR As String

ROOM = InputBox("What is Room?", "Room Numner")
SiteName = InputBox("What is the Site Name?", "Site Name")
SiteID = InputBox("What is the Site ID?", "Site ID")
FSR = InputBox("What is your Name?", "Your Name")

Range("A3").Value = ROOM
Range("B3").Value = SiteName
Range("C3").Value = SiteID
Range("G3").Value = FSR
Range("D3").Value = Date

 Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xNewWb As Workbook
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xFolderPath As Variant
    Dim xDlg As FileDialog
    Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook

    
*'> FileName = "needed' A3+C3+D3... problem here, I need these cells to added to next section*


    xFileName = InputBox("Enter file name here, : ")
    If xFileName = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xDlg.Show = -1 Then
        xFolderPath = xDlg.SelectedItems(1)
        xWb.ActiveSheet.Range("b1:H41").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Set xNewWb = Workbooks.Add
        Range("b1:H41").PasteSpecial
        xNewWb.SaveAs xFolderPath & "\" & xFileName & ".xlsx"
        xNewWb.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not `FileName = ROOM & SiteID & Date` rather than using the cells.

Answer (score 0):

In the idea that the best way to learn is by getting good examples a rewrote your script using arrays vs vars and minimalizing the interactions with the sheets but rather moving it in memory.

```
    Option Explicit
    Option Base 1
    
    Public Sub EnterInfo()
        Dim i As Long, arr, topics, xFileName As String
        'instead of hardcoding vars we store the messages in an array
        topics = Array( _
            "What is Room?", _
            "What is the Site Name?", _
            "What is the Site ID?", _
            "What is your Name?" _
            )
        
        'with the values in an array we can now automate the iterations and write the responses and to all manipulations like get responses, setup the filename string, ...
        ReDim arr(1 To UBound(topics), 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(topics)
            arr(i, 1) = InputBox(topics(i))
            xFileName = xFileName & CStr(arr(i, 1))
        Next i
        
        'all has been done in memory so we write to sheet
        With Sheet2
            .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, UBound(arr))).Value2 = arr
        End With
        
        'Get data for new workbook into an array
        Dim arr2
        arr2 = Sheet2.Range("B1:H41").Value2
            
        'save file in user selected folder
        Dim sFolder As String, xNewWb As Workbook
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
                sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
                Set xNewWb = Workbooks.Add
                With xNewWb.Sheets(1)
                    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(41, 8)).Value2 = arr2
                End With
                xFileName = InputBox("Enter file name here, : ", , xFileName)
                xNewWb.SaveAs sFolder & "\" & xFileName & ".xlsx"
                xNewWb.Close
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

keep on coding and don't hesitate if you have any additional questions.

Comment: this works perfectly, I appreciate your assistance, I've been out of practice to 12+ year, need to brush up and learn new/better ways

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you accept as answer. Thx